# Converting Express route with params from String ( '/page/:page' ) to RegExp ( /page/:page ) not working

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I'm simply trying to convert a route defined as String into one defined as RegExp.

```
app.get('/page/:page', handler);
```

This works, but converting it to RegExp doesn't work, the handler never fires:

```
app.get(/page\/\:page/, handler);
```

I've tried it with a couple of different ways, none seem to work

```
app.get(/page\/\:page/, handler);
app.get(/page\/:page/, handler);
app.get(/page/:page/, handler); // error
app.get(new RegExp('/page/:page'), handler);
app.get(new RegExp('/page\/\:page/'), handler);
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Also not working

```
app.get(/\/page\/:page/, handler);
app.get(new RegExp('\/page\/:page'), handler);
```

---

My URL would be something like `/page/xyz` where I'll be able to get `'xyz'` as `req.params.page`.

Comment: What does the URL look like, do you really have `:page` in the URL

Comment: @adeneo My URL would be something like `/page/xyz` where I'll be able to get `'xyz'` as `req.params.page`.

Comment: Scroll down for example: http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.param, though I don't know if it actually applies in this case. (I've never touched node.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:var`-type syntax only works with strings. For actual RegExps you have to use normal capturing groups (e.g. `/^\/page\/([^/]+)/`). These captures are then available on [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) as `req.params[0]`, `req.params[1]`, etc.